# how to get last inserted record by username in sql server

Tags: sql-server

emp Table record Like:

**empt Table**

```
id  name    date    
1   ankit   18-12-2014 05:55:22.000
2   mehul   18-12-2014 04:44:22.000
3   vimal   18-12-2014 03:44:22.000
4   ankit   18-12-2014 06:00:22.000
5   mehul   18-12-2014 06:10:22.000
```

I want to output like:

```
4 ankit 18-12-2014 06:00:22.000
5 mehul 18-12-2014 06:10:22.000
3 vimal 18-12-2014 03:44:22.000
```

when insert new record like this :

```
vimal   18-12-2014 06:30:22.000
```

then output like:

```
4 ankit 18-12-2014 06:00:22.000
5 mehul 18-12-2014 06:10:22.000
6 vimal 18-12-2014 06:30:22.000
```

so how to possible this?

Comment: Why not one of 1/2 in your first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx), since you want one record per username, this would be your partitioning field in the `OVER` clause (`PARTITION BY Name`), and then you want the latest record per username, so this would be your order in the `OVER` clause (`ORDER BY Date DESC`):

```
SELECT  ID, Name, Date
FROM    (   SELECT  ID, 
                    Name, 
                    Date,
                    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name 
                                                    ORDER BY Date DESC)
            FROM    T
        ) AS T
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: You can also use `GROUP BY ID ORDER BY Date Desc`

Answer (score 0):

an alternative solution could be a join:

```
select K.*
from (
       select  X.Name, 
               max(X.Date) MaxDate
       from    emp X
     ) Y
     join emp K on K.name = Y.name and K.Date = Y.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0):

N=NUMBER OF TABLE'S ROWS

```
 DECLARE @X INT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM empt  )
    SELECT ID, 
           Name, 
           Date 
    FROM empt  
    ORDER BY ID OFFSET (@X-3) ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```